# Customization buffer is not killed by Exit action, why?

Tags: emacs

I opened emacs.  According to Help -> About, it's using a Gtk 3 interface.

(I notice the `q` key kills this About buffer).

Options -> Customize Emacs -> Top-level Customization Groups, opens a Customize buffer.  I get a new menu Custom, which shows an Exit action, associated with the shortcut key `q`.

However pressing the `q` key does not kill the buffer.  It only switches back to a different buffer, but the Customize buffer remains open.

Using the Exit menu item, or the Exit button on the toolbar, does exactly the same.

Why?

---

Fedora 27 Workstation

emacs-25.3-3.fc27.x86_64